# Ruby on Rails - error running server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, table-structure

am currently working on a rails project. When i tried to start rails server its throwing the following error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters      
/sqlite_adapter.rb:439:in `table_structure': Could not find table 'dbrick'   
(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

My table name is 'dbrick'. I also Tried to rake db:drop and rake db:mirgrate. While migrating its throwing the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Could not find table 'dbrick'

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is my migrate file:

```
class CreateDbricks < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
  create_table :dbricks do |t|
    t.text :description
    t.string :video
    t.string :video_html
    t.string :image_id
    t.string :option_id
    t.boolean :choice
    t.string :reach
    t.integer :category_id
    t.string :user_id
    t.datetime :deleted_at

    t.timestamps
  end
end

 def self.down
   drop_table :dbricks
 end
end
```

It will be so much help full if any one help me out of this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have a typo: migration creates `dbricks`, but the code tries to use `dbrick` table. (plural vs singular form)

Comment: thanks for your reply. ya i have tried rake db:schema:load, but it gives the same error i.e   rake aborted!
Could not find table 'dbrick'

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: where should i change the code to make dbrick to plural form, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try :

```
rake db:schema:load
```

To load your schema ( to which I believe its finding the error against your DB ).

If that fails, I would manually find the migration that creates your dbrick, locate the name of the file and copy and paste the number in the filename to produce this :

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=123412341234 # <-- where the number is the number you pasted
```

Look for errors. Occasionally one thing exists already, or doesn't exist already and prevents the migration from running all the way, and consequentially that would be the source of your error. If it goes successfully then rake it back up :

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=123412341234 # <-- where the number is the number you pasted
```

If it doesn't go successfully, then you'll have to put on your miner's helmet, and get your hands dirty with :

```
rails dbconsole
```

Which will take you into your database and you'll have to manually delete whatever table/column is preventing the migration from occurring. Once that is fixed, exit out and `rake db:migrate:up`!

Comment: Awesome! What was the solution? Don't forget to give upvotes and set an answer as correct if its worth it.

Comment: I just did rake db:migrate down and db:migrate up.. Its worked thanks alot

Comment: No upvotes or marked answer? tsk tsk tsk.. :) Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Have you migrated your database? `rake db:migrate`

If you have, drop your database (this deletes all data, so be careful - do it if you do not care about losing data in your db)

```
rake db:drop
```

This will clear out your database, and your schema. Then

```
rake db:migrate
```

This will re-migrate your schema.

Comment: thanks for replying.. ya i dropped and migrated as you said.. dropping is done but while migrating am geting the error `rake aborted!
Could not find table 'dbrick'

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)`

Comment: @Abhiram thats weird. Maybe one of your migrations is doing something with the table dbrick before the dbrick create migrations is even created.